# Как создать фильтр для продуктов на React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Есть компоненты React**

***Main.jsx***

```
import React from "react";
import { Products } from "../Products";
import { Filter } from "../Filter";
import { Product } from "../Product";

class Main extends React.Component {
  state = {
    products: [],
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("./products.json")
      .then((responce) => responce.json())
      .then((data) => this.setState({ products: Object.values(data) }));
  }

  productFilter = (type = "all") => {
    const selected = [];
    return this.state.products.map((product) => {
      if (product.prod_status.contains(type)) {
        selected.push(product);
      }
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { products } = this.state;

    return (
      <main className="container content">
        <Filter />
        <Products products={products} />
      </main>
    );
  }
}

export { Main };
```

***Filter.jsx***

```
import React from "react";

class Filter extends React.Component {
  state = {
    type: "all",
  };

  hadleFilter = (event) => {
    this.setState({ type: event.target.dataset.type }, () => {
      this.props.productFilter(this.state.type);
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div clasName="row">
        <div className="sort_container">
          <h3 className="sort_title">Sortować według:</h3>
          <label>
            <input
              className="with-gap"
              name="prod-status"
              type="radio"
              data-type="all"
              onChange={this.hadleFilter}
              checked={this.state.type === "all"}
            />
            <span>All</span>
          </label>
          <label>
            <input
              className="with-gap"
              name="prod-status"
              type="radio"
              data-type="recommended"
              onChange={this.hadleFilter}
              checked={this.state.type === "recommended"}
            />
            <span>Recommended</span>
          </label>
          <label>
            <input
              className="with-gap"
              name="prod-status"
              type="radio"
              data-type="saleout"
              onChange={this.hadleFilter}
              checked={this.state.type === "saleout"}
            />
            <span>Saleout</span>
          </label>
          <label>
            <input
              className="with-gap"
              name="prod-status"
              type="radio"
              data-type="bestseller"
              onChange={this.hadleFilter}
              checked={this.state.type === "bestseller"}
            />
            <span>Bestseller</span>
          </label>
          <label>
            <input
              className="with-gap"
              name="prod-status"
              type="radio"
              data-type="promotion"
              onChange={this.hadleFilter}
              checked={this.state.type === "promotion"}
            />
            <span>Rromotion</span>
          </label>
          <label>
            <input
              className="with-gap"
              name="prod-status"
              type="radio"
              data-type="new"
              onChange={this.hadleFilter}
              checked={this.state.type === "new"}
            />
            <span>New</span>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export { Filter };
```

**Cсылка на весь репозиторий - [тут](https://github.com/YevheniiBrodovskyii/Sky-shop-Task-React-)**

***Вопрос-*** **попытался сделать функцию  productFilter() в Main.jsx, которую передаю в Filter.jsx для реализации фильтра после нажатия на любой radio. Ясное дело, что функция написана не правильно, прошу помочь исправить ошибки и довести фильтр в рабочее состояние**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю следующее решение

(Я немного упростил кол-во фильтров и набор данных для удобства работы с примером, а также переписал на функциональные компоненты, однако суть задачи и ее решения от этого совершенно не изменилась)

```js
const {useState, useCallback, useMemo} = React;

const data = [
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "delectus aut autem",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "quis ut nam facilis et officia qui",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "fugiat veniam minus",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 4,
    "title": "et porro tempora",
    "completed": true
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 5,
    "title": "laboriosam mollitia et enim quasi adipisci quia provident illum",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 6,
    "title": "qui ullam ratione quibusdam voluptatem quia omnis",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 7,
    "title": "illo expedita consequatur quia in",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 8,
    "title": "quo adipisci enim quam ut ab",
    "completed": true
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 9,
    "title": "molestiae perspiciatis ipsa",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 10,
    "title": "illo est ratione doloremque quia maiores aut",
    "completed": true
  }
]


const COMPLETE_FILTER = {
  Completed: "completed",
  Incompleted: "incompleted",
  All: "all"
};

const TodoItem = ({ title, completed }) => {
  return (
    <article className={"todoItem"}>
      <h4>{title}</h4>
      <div>
        completed:{" "}
        <span className={completed ? "completed" : "incompleted"}>
          {String(completed)}
        </span>
      </div>
    </article>
  );
};

const TodoList = ({ list = [] }) => {
  return (
    <main>
      {list.map(({ title, completed, id }) => (
        <TodoItem key={id} title={title} completed={completed} />
      ))}
    </main>
  );
};

const FilterItem = ({ checked, name, onChange }) => {
  return (
    <label>
      {name}
      <input
        checked={checked}
        type="radio"
        name={name}
        value={name}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
    </label>
  );
};

const FiltersPanel = ({ curFilter, updateFilter }) => {
  const onFiltersChange = (event) => {
    const newFilter = event.target.value;
    updateFilter(newFilter);
  };

  return (
    <form className={"filters-panel"}>
      <h2>Select filter</h2>
      <FilterItem
        checked={curFilter === COMPLETE_FILTER.All}
        name={COMPLETE_FILTER.All}
        onChange={onFiltersChange}
      />
      <FilterItem
        checked={curFilter === COMPLETE_FILTER.Completed}
        name={COMPLETE_FILTER.Completed}
        onChange={onFiltersChange}
      />
      <FilterItem
        checked={curFilter === COMPLETE_FILTER.Incompleted}
        name={COMPLETE_FILTER.Incompleted}
        onChange={onFiltersChange}
      />
    </form>
  );
};

function App() {
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState(COMPLETE_FILTER.All);

  /**
   * Функция-утилита, содержащая в себе логику по фильтрации данных для отображения
   * @param list - массив данных, которые мы будем фильтровать
   * @param curFilter - текущее знач-е фильтра
   */
  const getfilteredTodos = (list, curFilter = COMPLETE_FILTER.All) => {
    if (curFilter === COMPLETE_FILTER.All) return list;

    const needCompleted = curFilter === COMPLETE_FILTER.Completed;

    return list.filter((item) => item.completed === needCompleted);
  };

  /**
   * Здесь мы сохраняем уже отфильтрованные данные
   * Я использовал переменную с useMemo, т.к. в моем случае данные статичны
   * Если вы будете загружать данные с сервера, то просто используйте вместо этого варианта - состояние (для функц. компонетн useState)
   */
  const filteredTodos = useMemo(() => getfilteredTodos(data, filter), [filter]);

  /**
   * Обработчик смены текущего фильтра
   */
  const handleFilterUpdate = useCallback((newFilter) => {
    setFilter(newFilter);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <FiltersPanel curFilter={filter} updateFilter={handleFilterUpdate} />
      <TodoList list={filteredTodos} />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
}

body {
  background: #e4e4e4;
}

main {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 2px dashed lightgray;
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
}

.todoItem {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}

.completed {
  color: lightgreen;
}

.incompleted {
  color: lightpink;
}

.filters-panel {
  border: 2px dashed lightgray;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Если вам захочется посмотреть на решение изнутри, то вот [ссылка на sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-forest-eq78j3?file=/src/App.js)